# Add rows to dataframes from list of dataframes until number of rows is 1000 for every data frame in list

Tags: r, list, rbind

I have a list with dataframes, each of them has a different number of rows. Now I'd like to add rows to every dataframe of the list, until every dataframe of the list has 1000 rows. The added rows should all only contain NAs. All dataframes of the list contain of three columns.

I first defined the function

```
adder <- function(x) {rbind(x, c(NA, NA, NA))}
```

and then applied it to every dataframe of the list using lapply

```
dflisttest <- lapply(dflisttest, adder)
```

However, this would add one row to every dataframe rather than only to the ones that have less than 1000 rows. How could I loop it so that all dataframes of the list automatically fill up to 1000 rows?

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. Please provide an MCVE. for example, do each of the data.frames have the same number of columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(rep(1,8),rep(2,4)),
                 y=c(rep(0,8),rep(5,4))
```

and you want to bind values (NA) till its nrow=1000, you can try:

```
adder <- function(x) {

        if(nrow(x)<1000)
                x[(nrow(x)+1):1000,] <- NA

        return(x)
}
```

This function adds NA in all columns after the last row till row#1000

**Example**:  added NA after row 12 which was the original size of df.

```
> df <- adder(df)
> df[10:16,]
    x  y
10  2  5
11  2  5
12  2  5
13 NA NA
14 NA NA
15 NA NA
16 NA NA
```

Comment: what if data.frame already had 1000 rows?... prefer `return(x[1:1000,]`

Comment: thanks, using now lapply on the adder function worked!